# blender engine mirror

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem setting up the reflections for my water in the blender internal rendering engine, as you can see on the picture, the grass doesn't appear in the mirror...they are hair particles over the land mesh. I tried to convert them into a mesh but it doesn't render either. Water mirror is set to 1 with a fresnel of 0.5 and a blend of 3.

[image: overview]

Comment: Are you using strand-render for the grass? Strand does not reflect, turning that off in the particles panel should fix it.

Comment: awh yes man it is right, without strand render on I do get the reflections. Thanks